# how to insert video to fluid player in blogger

Tags: video, blogger, fluid

I am using fluid player for my blogger website to upload videos but I don't know how to insert videos into it because normal video sites links don't work here but the videos link like this video this video -(bit.ly/3jKTFrb) work here so how can I convert my video to this type video link?

Answer (score 0):

Please post the code which you are using for me to tell you how to add your videos into it.